# msbuild replace build tools automatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I'm using VS2012 to build a package created with VS2013, the problem is that the project uses build tool `v110_xp`, where I only have version `v110`

During msbuild, it complains,

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform
.targets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v110_xp (Platform Toolset =
 'v110_xp') cannot be found. To build using the v110_xp build tools, either cli
ck the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ P
rojects...". Install v110_xp to build using the v110_xp build tools. [c:\\xxx.vcxproj]
```

Of course, in the VS IDE, I can edit the version for each project.

But I'm wondering if there's a way to ignore the missing tools, let msbuild use whatever is available.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but try using /p:PlatformToolset=v110 on the msbuild command line.

Comment: @Wurmloch It works, awesome

Comment: The v110_xp toolset was added to VS2012 later, after it was released.  So a simple explanation is that you don't have its updates installed.  Be sure to get at least Update 3.  Why you can't simply change the Toolset selection in the IDE is hard to guess, most obvious way to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm building projects maintained by other people on github, and it has 4 sub projects. What I'm doing is automating the build process

Comment: Hmm, is there any real point in automating a build and getting the wrong build produced?  Get the updates installed, easy peasy.  Not just because of the missing toolset but also for the (considerable) number of bugs in C++ compiler.  VS2012 was a very heavy release for C++, it had a completely new compiler back-end that supports auto-vectorization and SSE code generation, not to mention lots of C++11 changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the used platform toolset using the msbuild command line like this:

> msbuild.exe /p:PlatformToolset=v110 [...]